# Unable to combine sonar.authenticator.createUsers=false with the LDAP plugin in sonarqube 5.6.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

If I perform the following

- add the LDAP plugin and configure it correctly
- set `sonar.authenticator.createUsers=false`

then the [docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) say

> Setting this value to false, makes it mandatory for a System administrator to first declare a user through the SonarQube web interface before allowing this user to log into SonarQube.

However if I go to the admin console and create a user then it is created as a local user and there is no way to change this at present.

Is there a way to do this in 5.6.x?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the description of `sonar.authenticator.createUsers=false` is false.
I'll update it to "Allow new users to authenticate. When set to 'false', only existing users will be able to authenticate to the server."